# Mapview: edit map - Raster image too large; 19177520 bytes is greater than maximum 4194304 bytes

Tags: r, raster, sentinel

I was trying to create a supervised classification with Sentinel image via R but the mapview function cannot show the map because the raster image is said to be large. I already set the default to InF (infinite) but still shows the same error. Is there a way out of this?

[image]

Below is the R code that I was using:

```
points<-viewRGB(Sentinel, r = 4, g = 3, b = 2, maxpixels =  Inf) %>% editMap()
```

and this was the error message I am receiving:

[image]

I don't know if you guys can see the pictures.

Comment: Probably related to https://github.com/r-spatial/mapview/issues/272. The parameter `maxpixels`  is ignored.

Comment: Does it mean up until now it wasn't fixed?

Comment: The parameter is being ignored since March 22th. But you could open a new issue on Github.